# grand total column in Impala using window function

Tags: window-functions, impala

I'm looking for a way to do a "grand total" column across ALL groups in Impala.

It's easy to use window functions to obtain total of partitioned groups like this:

sum(x) over (partition by A)

however it does not appear that there is an expression to partition by 'all'. Is this a shortcoming in Impala? It looks like in postgress you can leave the over statement blank.

Answer (score 0):

The partition clause is optional. You can write a query like this:

```
select sum(x) over () from t;
```

For example:

```
[localhost:21000] > select id, sum(id) over () from tbl;
+----+-------------------+
| id | sum(id) OVER(...) |
+----+-------------------+
| 0  | 28                |
| 1  | 28                |
| 2  | 28                |
| 3  | 28                |
| 6  | 28                |
| 7  | 28                |
| 4  | 28                |
| 5  | 28                |
+----+-------------------+
Fetched 8 row(s) in 0.08s
```

Comment: for some reason I can't do this. I get:

errorMessage:AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): sum(X) OVER ()

The issue is not in the overall query GROUP BY clause (it's very simple, grouping by one column). I can use the Analytic function if i include a partition by statement.

Comment: Something else is wrong with your query. Can you post more of the query?

Comment: SELECT
a.app
,sum(a.rev) as 'rev_by group'
,sum(a.rev) over () as 'total'
from rev_table a
group by a.app

results in: 
select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): sum(a.rev) OVER ()

I don't understand the only other non-aggregated column is already included in the GROUP BY clause... not sure how to interpret this. thanks for your help btw

Comment: You mixing aggregation and window functions. Please find solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201554/partition-by-in-impala-sql-throwing-an-error

Answer (score 0):

If empty partition clause does not work, try partition by hardcoded value.  Unlike aggregate sql, no need to comment out other columns

> select count(1) over (partition by 1) AS count_all, q.* from q