# Partition by in Impala SQL throwing an error

Tags: sql, group-by, window-functions, impala

I am trying to calculate the running total of loss by the months on Impala using TOAD

The following query is throwing the error -**select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from group by clause )**

```
select
segment,
year(open_dt) as open_year,
months,
sum(balance)
sum(loss) over (PARTITION by segment,year(open_dt) order by months) as NCL 
from

tableperf
where
year(open_dt) between 2015 and 2018

group by 1,2,3
```

Comment: You should include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing aggregation and window functions.  I think you might want:

```
select segment, year(open_dt) as open_year, months,
       sum(balance)
       sum(sum(loss)) over (PARTITION by segment, year(open_dt) order by months) as NCL 
from tableperf
where year(open_dt) between 2015 and 2018
group by 1, 2, 3;
```

This calculates the cumulative loss within each year.  Note the use of `sum(sum(loss))`.  The inner `sum()` is an aggregation function.  The outer `sum()` is a window function.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, where can I find the documents about the syntax for mixing the use of aggregation and window functions?

Comment: @lovechillcool . . . I don't actually know.  The syntax conventions work together and window functions are evaluated *after* aggregation.